# How is encoded the information on the surface of the volume' s boundary?

Tags: ads-cft, information, holographic-principle

In the context of the  holographic principle, who states that the entropy of ordinary mass (not just black holes) 
is also proportional to surface area and not volume;that volume itself is illusory and the universe is really 
a hologram which is isomorphic to the information "inscribed" on the surface of its boundary.

How is encoded the information on the surface of the volume' s boundary ?